# Text Justification problem of "Introduction to algorithm"

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

The problem that I currently went through is kind of text justification problem. The problem is given that there is a paragraph and a some blank lines. We want to print this paragraph neatly on the number of lines that hold a maximum of M characters each. So, if the paragraph is "Roses are red and sky is blue" and we were told that M=10 then we can divide the paragraph in between the lines in various ways

```
Roses are  //space left 1  cost can be 1+3+4+6 =13
red and   //space left 3  //It seems same cost for two arrangements. But if we take the cube o 
sky is   //space left 4      of the spaces 1+27+64+216 = 308
blue    // space left 6

Roses   //space left 5 cost can be 5+3+3+2 =13 //cube of spaces
are red //space left 3                         // 125+27+27+8= 187
and sky // space left 3      //If we take cubes it seems 2nd arrangement is more cost effective
is blue // space left 2
```

The question says, We wish to minimize the sum, over all lines except the last, of the cubes of the numbers of extra space characters at the ends of lines.

We need to solve this using dynamic programing.

I also went through this solution for the problem [Solution to Problem 15-4](https://viterbi-web.usc.edu/%7Eshanghua/teaching/Spring2010/public_html/files/HW3_Solutions_A.pdf)

I figured out the first recurrence relation as follows

[image]

But I could not figure out how could I make table for c[j] recurrence relation.

This is the problem from chapter 15 Dynamic programming problem 15-4 of Introduction to Algorithms, Cormen.

Any help would be appreciated.